# How accurately do Airy discs need to be superimposed in an optical interferometer to create fringes?

Tags: optics, astronomy, interferometry

In an astronomical optical interferometer, what is the largest amount of error in the alignment of the Airy disks of point source star images from different arms of the interferometer that will still create interference fringes (and the smallest Airy disk)?

I'm not sure what conditions we need to define to get an answer, but if it's helpful, assume that we're looking at point source star images (not a star disk that might be resolved by a very large interferometer) at the wavelength of yellow light (580 nm), and that the answer is a percentage of the diameter of the Airy disk (which I think would give an answer that would be independent of the interferometer aperture).  Would this answer be different at different wavelengths of visible light?

Comment: The interference from two arms will not make the Airy disks smaller, it will merely lead to a very narrow interference pattern across the disks. As long as you can get the two images to overlap, there will be a visible interference pattern. That, of course, is not as easy as it sounds. The Airy disks of stars in larger instruments will have a diameter of a fraction of an arc second, so the alignment has to be as precise as maybe one hundredth to a tenth of an arc second while tracking the star to make the method useful. And, yes, all of this is wavelength dependent.

Comment: To clarify, my question is, what is the minimum extent that the Airy disk images need to overlap? Do they need to overlap 75% of the diameter of the Airy disk to produce fringes? 85%? 95%? More?

Comment: Like I said, I don't see a reason why there shouldn't be  interference at any overlap (for an ideal point source), however, if the overlap is small, the useful amount of light in the interference pattern will be small. For a sufficiently large instrument (exceeding about 10" aperture) the Airy disk is smaller than the seeing disk, anyway, which means that the interference will only happen when the two disks overlap by chance, unless one uses adaptive optics. While I haven't worked with an interferometer, I would think that seeing and the need for adaptive optics are the bigger concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  Seeing conditions and adaptive optics are definitely part of my thinking about this problem, as is speckle ("lucky") imaging and computer stacking of multiple images.

Comment: Sounds cool! Good luck with your project.